# Vue.js warns You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I'm quite new to Vue.js & Buefy and I believe I understand why this happens but have no idea how to fix it.

I have a list of project partners sorted by country and I need to output a list with checkboxes (I'm using Buefy on the page anyway) and country names as title (only when there's a "new" country). This ends with browser doing infinite loop (verified with console.log) and Vue Devtools gives warning "You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function".

I believe this happens because changing prevTitle triggers re-rendering. I know it's not possible to pass parameters to computed properties and I haven't been able to use any of the tricks I've found to make partner.country available there.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      prevTitle: ""
    ...

    methods: {
      changeCountryTitle(country) {
        if (country != this.prevTitle) {
          this.prevTitle = country;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
<template v-for="partner in results">
    <div v-if="changeCountryTitle(partner.country)">
        {{ partner.country }}
    </div>
    <b-checkbox ... >{{ partner.name }}, ...</b-checkbox>
    <br />
</template>
```

Then I tried to make a computed property where I do all processing instead of for loop in template and return a string that contains everything, including Buefy tags, which would be called

```
<span v-html="printPartnerList"></span>
```

But those Buefy tags don't get rendered properly, only HTML tags work, browser ignores Buefy tags showing the normal text only.

Any ideas how get this working? For time being I print country names for each partner after name etc. but it's not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: what is `results`?

Comment: Your method is evaluating every partner against the prevTitle to know if it should return true or false from your method.  But your method modifies that variable.  So by modifying it, all the partners have to be re-evaluated.

Comment: I get `results` from database, it is object containing id, name, country etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-html` doesn't evaluate Vue (or in this case Buefy) components, only regular HTML tags.

Your first approach wasn't that bad, but instead of calling a method inside the `v-for` you can add a computed property in the items that tells if the country should be rendered:

```
<template v-for="partner in computedResults">
    <div v-if="partner.showCountry">
        {{ partner.country }}
    </div>
    <b-checkbox ... >{{ partner.name }}, ...</b-checkbox>
    <br />
</template>
```

New app:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      // prevTitle: "" <- not needed
    ...

    computed: {
      computedResults() {
        let prevCountry = ''
        let newResults = []
        this.results.forEach(partner => {
          let showCountry = false
          if (prevCountry != partner.country) {
            showCountry = true
          }
          newResults.push({
            ...partner,
            showCountry
          })
          prevCountry = partner.country
        })
        return newResults
      }
```